# Does anyone knows which enconding is it?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

```
<E9> necess<E1>rio informar o MSISDN, ICCID e o ICCID solicitado para troca
```

"é necesário informar o MSISDN, ICCID e o ICCID solicitado para troca"

```
O CNPJ do cliente <E9> obrigat<F3>rio.
```

"o CNPJ do cliente é obrigatório"

I wonder which encoding it is

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that can "decode" it:

```
@Test public void testEncoding() {
    String s = "O CNPJ do cliente <E9> obrigat<F3>rio.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)<([A-Fa-f0-9]+)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int end = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        b.append(m.group(1));
        int cp = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2), 16);
        b.append((char)cp);
        end = m.end();
    }
    b.append(s.substring(end));
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

Comment: i'm afraid that's not what i need.  I need just to avoid the auto-decoding that eclipse and others text editors are doing to this encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know the encoding, but it appears to be a simple encoding of [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (or [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)), where non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters are encoded as 2-digit hex surrounded by `<>` angle brackets.